# how to clear cache search results from server in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel-5, caching, search

i'm new to laravel and i've created a simple search to query my database.
the problem is that everytime i refresh the page all the results from my last search are still showing. also when i load the page after couple of days,results are the. it seems like there is a cache working which i dont know about.
i want to clear these results/cache without clearing the cache for all my app.

Here is the code.

in my routs file:

```
Route::get('men',function()
{
  $query=Request::get('q'); 

   if ($query)
         {

              $users= \App\User::where('first_name','LIKE',"%$query%")
                                ->orwhere('last_name','LIKE',"%$query%")
                                ->get();


         }
         else
         {

         }

  return view('page')->withUsers($users); 

});
```

My View:(page.blade.php)

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'GET']) !!}
    <div class="container col-lg-6 form-group" style="float:none;margin:auto">
    <div class="input-group">    
    {!! Form::input('search','q', null, ['placeholder' => 'search' , 
    'class' => 'form-control', 'autocomplete' => 'off']) !!}
    <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Search</button>
    </div><!-- /btn-group -->
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}

<div class="container col-lg-6" style="float:none;margin:auto">
  @if ($users->count())
      <ul class="list-group" style="list-style-type: none;">
      @foreach($users as $user)

              <li class="list-group-item" style="cursor:pointer">
                  {{$user->first_name}} {{$user->last_name}}
              </li>

      @endforeach
      </ul>
  @else

      <h3>Sorry,no users found...</h3>

  @endif
</div>


</div>  <!--container-->
```

any Ideas ??..

Answer (score 0):

i've managed to clear last query string in the browser addess bar with:

within my view:

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
var uri = window.location.toString();
if (uri.indexOf("?") > 0) {
    var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("?"));
    window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_uri);
}
</script>

</head>
```

whenever i refresh the page it clears up the results since nothing is coming from the server.